# Calculate $\mathop{\lim}\limits_{z\to 0} \, \frac{e^z+z\mathrm{Log}z}{1-z^2\mathrm{Arg}z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I don't know how to compute the $\underset{z\rightarrow 0}{lim } \, \frac{e^z+zLogz}{1-z^2Argz}$

First, does $\lim{z\to 0}
\mathrm{Arg}z  $ exist ?
If we take $z_n= \frac{1}{n}+i\frac{1}{n}$ and $w_n= \frac{1}{n}-i\frac{1}{n}$ we can see that it doesn't (I think) isnt that a problem when we will take the $lim zArgz$ or i would just do $0$?
Secondary, how can i compute $z\mathrm{Log}z$ can i use L'Hôpital's rule on complex analysis ?
Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit of $\mbox{Arg} z$ does not exist, but limit of $z^2 \mbox{Arg} z$  does (it equals $0.$ Similarly, $\log z$ is not defined at $0,$ and the limit does not exist, but the limit of $z \log z$ does exist (and equals zero). Prove the above two statements and you are good.